Do it must exist conjugate of roots if deg of a separable polynomial is more than 2?
I'm studying now for galois-theory. I see the lemma that was
Let  ⊂
, 
is splitting field over 
of a separable polynomal $p(x) \in F[x]$, then $E_G$=F ,$E_G=\{ a 
 \in E:\forall \sigma \in G , \sigma(a)=a\}$ ,where G is $G(E/F)$ $G(E/F)=\{ \sigma: \sigma(a)=a \ \forall a \in F ,\ \sigma \ is  \ automorphism \ \sigma :E  \ \rightarrow  E \}$, so I want to prove the lemma with if $\alpha \in E$, $\alpha \notin F$ ,
$p(\alpha) =0$ ,then $\exists \sigma \in G$  s.t $\sigma(\alpha) =\beta$, s.t $\beta$ is conjugate of $\alpha$. but it need below assumption is true.
Let $ \space  F \subset  E $, $E$  is   splitting  field   over $F$  of  a  separable  polynomal,
If deg of the polynomial is more than 2,  Do it  must exist conjugate of roots in $E?$
It will be helpful for me, if you give specific proof, or counter example.
Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you use MathJax formatting, capital letters etc., please?

I fixed it. Thank you for your feedback

If $E$ is the splitting field over $F$ of some polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$, and $\alpha \in E\setminus F$ is a root of $p(x)$, then the minimal polynomial $\phi_\alpha(x)$ of $\alpha$ must divide $p(x)$: $p(x) = \phi_\alpha(x)h(x)$ for some $h(x) \in F[x]$. The conjugates of $\alpha$ are by definition the other roots of $\phi_\alpha(x)$. And thus they are all roots of $p(x)$ as well. Which means the splitting field $E$ must contain all of them.
